# How to disable click while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src=""><img src=""><img src=""><img src=""><img src=""><img src="">
  <div class="vid"></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
jQuery(".container").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.85,
        axis: "x",
        containment: [-wystaje, 0, 0, 0]
    });
```

and

```
jQuery('img').each(function () {
  jQuery('.vid').fadeIn("slow");
 });
```

Now when I click on an image and drag, the div "vid" appears.
How to do that:

I click on an image, drag, release the mouse button, then click on an image and the div "vid" appears?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
.container{ 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 400px;
}

.vid { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    display: none;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
}
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".container").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.85,
        axis: "x"
    });

    jQuery('img').click(function () {
        jQuery('.vid').fadeIn("slow");
    });

});
```